# how to insert the correct activex object in a MFC dialog

Tags: windows, mobile, controls, browser

More exactly, the web browser control. In a WM6 dialog based MFC project. This is driving me nuts. Mr Google does not know a thing on this matter. I have tried embedding the "Microsoft Webbrowser Control" in my dialog box but at runtime I get some class not register error. I have heard that this happens because "Microsoft Webbrowser Control" is the windows desktop control, not the windows mobile one. 
Otherwise, I find it quite hard to believe that this control is really not registered even on the emulator (if it really wasn't registered, PIE would not start).

Anybody used the webbrowser engine in a WM(6) MFC applications ? Even a CLSID would help...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Utilizing Pocket IE Functionality in Mobile Applications](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/ce/controls/article.php/c6813/)